# Can a paradox exist in another paradox?

Tags: paradox

Question is whether another paradox can exist inside another paradox when that paradox is happening?

Comment: How do paradoxes happen?

Comment: What does it mean for a paradox to exist within another paradox?

Comment: Please explain what you mean. Your question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: its an enigma wrapped up in a mystery...

Comment: @ankur  , what i meant is ,if  a  paradox triggers to occurs will it be stopped by another paradox ,which prevents the first paradox to occur..

Comment: @AmruthA What do you mean by a paradox existing?

Comment: Sir, your statement in itself is a paradox. Look closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This paragraph is false. This sentence is false.